# How do I test if the player in an onPlayerRenameItem event has a certain permission?

Tags: java, bukkit

I made an anvil Color rename plugin but i want to restrict the feature to users with a specific permission. The current code throws this error: The method getPlayer() is undefined for the type PrepareAnvilEvent
My listener:

```
package com.delight.anvilcolorrename;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.PrepareAnvilEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

public class AnvilColorRenameListener implements Listener {
    
    //Constructor
    public AnvilColorRenameListener(Main plugin) {
        
    }

    //EventHandler
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerRenameItem(PrepareAnvilEvent event){
        if (event.getPlayer().hasPermission("AnvilColorRename.use")) {
            if(event.getResult() != null && event.getResult().hasItemMeta() && event.getInventory().getRenameText() != ""){
                ItemStack result = event.getResult();
                ItemMeta resultMeta = result.getItemMeta();
                String nameColored = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', event.getInventory().getRenameText());
                resultMeta.setDisplayName(nameColored);
                result.setItemMeta(resultMeta);
            }
            }// if(!event.hasPermission("AnvilColorRename.use")) {
//                event.sendMessage("You can not use color codes in an anvil!");
//            }
    }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official Spigot javadocs: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot

The [PrepareAnvilEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/PrepareAnvilEvent.html) class does not have a method that returns a player.

Comment: So is it impossible to check that?

Comment: You will need to use another event. Take a look at the InventoryClickEvent: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/InventoryClickEvent.html

Comment: I now used
Player player = inventoryClickEvent.getWhoClicked();
but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Please post a more accurate description of "I can't get it to work" and your code.

Comment: oh yeah mb.
https://pastebin.com/bSaWPGsT
inventoryClickEvent cannot be resolved and Player cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You need to change the type of the event in the method signature from `PrepareAnvilEvent` to `InventoryClickEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `PrepareAnvilEvent` doesn't come with a `Player` field that you can access. However, you can get the `Player` via the `InventoryView`:

```java
event.getInventoryView().getPlayer()
```